# install ubuntu 12.04 with ati hd radeon 6850

Tags: 12.04, ati, radeon

The problem is that I can't even run installation, seems that the monitor isn't connected to PC.

I can't see anything, just black screen.

I had almost the same problem with Ubuntu 11.10 (couldn't solve it neither) though that newest version had better compability.

Comment: Do you have multiple graphic cards installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installation with

```
nomodeset
```

when the install is starting up, press `Esc` and then goto `more options` (I think... it's the right most option) and press `Enter` and select `nomodeset`.  That should let you boot.